# how can send multiple value by checkbox

Tags: php, ajax

i have write code by ajax to sent name and roles by ajax, the name send success, but checkbox not send when choose more than 2 roles.

ajax code

```
   var HttPRequest = false;

   function doCallAjax(Mode,Page,ID) {
      HttPRequest = false;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
         HttPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
         if (HttPRequest.overrideMimeType) {
            HttPRequest.overrideMimeType('text/html');
         }
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
         try {
            HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         } catch (e) {
            try {
               HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
         }
      } 

      if (!HttPRequest) {
         alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
         return false;
      }

      var url = 'AjaxRolesPermRecord.php';
      var pmeters = "troles_Name=" + encodeURI( document.getElementById("roles_Name").value) +
                    "&tper=" + encodeURI( document.getElementById("per").value) +
                    '&myPage='+Page +
                    "&tID=" + ID +
                    "&tMode=" + Mode;

        HttPRequest.open('POST',url,true);

        HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", pmeters.length);
        HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        HttPRequest.send(pmeters);


        HttPRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
        {

             if(HttPRequest.readyState == 3)  // Loading Request
              {
               document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = "load ...";
              }

             if(HttPRequest.readyState == 4) // Return Request
              {
               document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = HttPRequest.responseText;
              }

        }

   }
```

and i get it on other page like this

```
foreach($selected as $key=>$val) 
{  
    $SqlInsertIntotable = mysql_query("INSERT INTO permissions_roles (id,permission_id,role_id) 
                                       value ('','".$val."','".$RoleID."')"); 
}
```

the problem is

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: $selected is missing or empty..can't find it anywhere else in your code?

Comment: @Oli i get it on php page like this `$selected = $_POST["tper"]; `

Comment: add an alert(pmeters) after the 'var pmeters' and check if all data is filled in

Comment: its like this `troles_Name=admin&tper=1&myPage=1&tID=&tMode=ADD` but tper we must take more than one value

Comment: on my code here `"&tper=" + encodeURI( document.getElementById("per").value) +` we must get more than one value how can do that

Answer (score 0):

Are the checkboxs defined like an array?
For example:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]">
```

Comment: how can i defined it by array on my code and get it on php page

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="val"> <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="val2">`

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]">

Comment: i will defined `<input type="checkbox" name="per[]" id="per" value="<?=$objResult['permission_id']; ?>" /> <?=$objResult['permission_name']; ?>` and get same problem

Comment: If you do it without ajax, but with a classic form, it works?

Comment: You can get only the selected checkboxes and sent it one for param to the server

Answer (score 0):

[Pass all checkboxes values as an array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791296/pass-all-checkboxes-values-as-an-array-in-javascript)

This deals with your problem of selecting values and passing them to 'tper'